# Iterate over and fetch each element of string having values separated by \n delimiter without using split

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, csv

I've a input string such as

```
1
29
315
4597
5
6
```

Each of the number is separated by a \n delimiter, in regular cases what I would do is just use split() method to get an array of these numbers like `["1","29","315","4597","5","6"]` and then iterate over the array to get each of the element inside it.

Is there a way of fetching these elements without generating an array of such numbers and directly pulling out these numbers individually along with their indexes from the string itself?

Comment: No. Split -> iterate is how one would usually do it. There is no _"Iterate over specifc parts of this string"_ method.

Comment: split() is the best way to achieve this. What do you not want to create an array? any specific problem?

Comment: Not sure about best way I kindof want to implement something mentioned in this SO reply that I got on one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159586/why-elastic-search-bulk-insert-uses-n-delimiter-instead-of-using-an-array-of-j)

Comment: @TGW: And what makes you think that _doesn't_ use `split`? To me, it looks like that that's ___exactly___ what is used.

Comment: @Cerbrus I believe they're not creating an array as clearly mentioned they don't want it to be loaded in memory, split does return me an array. Also ES is developed in java so they don't have that method, but I am just wondering is there a workaroud which is somehow faster but not good maybe because that workaroud might have some other more costly and unwanted effects

Comment: @TGW: You're misinterpreting the answer. They're not loading the entire ___parsed___ json into memory. They're extracting only that one array as string, then parsing that. That __extraction__ can only be done using something like `split`.

Comment: @Cerbrus that seems interesting, from what I understand of your comment, they ultimately do use some mechanism like split to extract data, but is it necessary that the mechanism shall be returning some kind of arraylike datastructure?

Comment: They ultimately use some mechanism like split to extract a string from the complete JSON, ___then___ parse that extracted JSON string into actual data.

Comment: oh, thanks the comments did explain a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could write a generator function that loops the source char by char and yields a line once it finds a newline symbol:

```js
function* lines(source) {
    let buf = '';

    for (let char of source) {
        if (char === '\n') {
            yield buf;
            buf = '';
        } else
            buf += char;
    }

    if (buf)
        yield buf;
}


source = `1
29
315
4597345345345
5
6`;

for (let line of lines(source))
  console.log(line)
```

If you also need indexes as you go, you can use this simple utility:

```
function* enumerate(it, start = 0) {
    for (let x of it)
        yield [start++, x];
}
```

and then

```
for (let [index, line] of enumerate(lines(source)))
    console.log(index, line)
```

Note that the "source" doesn't have to be a string, it can be any iterable object, e.g. a file, which is practical when your data cannot be kept in memory all at once.

Comment: Is iterating over every single character manually faster than a `split`?

Comment: Presumably not, but this generator would also work in situations where `.split` won't - e.g. when `source` is a stream too big to be read at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach. It is linear-time and doesn't create arrays.

```js
let str = "0\r\n1\n22\n333\r\n4\n55\n6\n777\r\n8888\n99999";

const fetch = (str, index) => {
    let i = 0, j = 0, value = "";
    while (j < index && i < str.length) {
        if (str[i++] === '\n') j++;
    }
    while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9' && i < str.length) value += str[i++];
    return value;
};

console.log(fetch(str, 7));
```

Comment: Well there goes maintainability.